# What is the correct way to separate routes in falcon Python?

Tags: python, falconframework

Examples, provided in documentation describe applications with one or few routes. Each url path has own class. What is the best practice for situation with lots of routes?
For example, I have following RESTFul structure:

localhost:8000/my_part/A

localhost:8000/my_part/B

localhost:8000/my_part/A/default

localhost:8000/my_part/B/special

and so on.

What should I do:

1. For each path create it's own class
2. Create single class for 'my_part' and somehow distinguish A, B in that class (for example with stripping req.uri)
3. Something else.

Notice that 'default ' and 'special' are not variables, but actual routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have really huge numbers of URLs (OR want to manage easily) then group them and store each in the different file.

i.e. You can group them as follow:

Let say you can group "/my_part/A", "/my_part/A/default" and so on and store them in let say "routes-a.py".

And similarly "/my_part/B", "/my_part/B/special" and so on and store them in let say "routes-b.py". 
After that just import all routes in single file and use it.

As I understand each one is URL, so each will have separate GET and POST request, so I think you should use the separate class only. Single class for all seems bad idea (maintenance will be very difficult in future in this case).

After that just import all file in single file and use it.

And also I suggest you write the class in a separate file only. Don't write everything in one file. So later you can easily identify using file name only.

Let take example again consider:
File "falcon_app.py"

```
import falcon
app = falcon.API()
```

file "routes_a.py" and have store required class in the file "class_A.py"

```
from class_A import *
from falcon_app import app
app.add_route("/my_part/A/", MyPartA())
app.add_route("/my_part/A/default/", MyPartADefault())
```

and
for file "routes_b.py" and have store required class in file "class_B.py"

```
from class_B import *
from falcon_app import app
app.add_route("/my_part/B/", MyPartB())
app.add_route("/my_part/B/special/", MyPartBSpecial())
```

Now, combine all in single file let say "routes.py"

```
from routes_a import *
from routes_b import *
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know if I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping them on different files is the best way so far, since there no blueprint concept here as it is on Flask.

Of course you can build a module that handles the routing for all of the classes/resource that belong to the same group, since all will live under the same prefix, say '/api/v1' and '/api/v2'

Particularly for this case, were more than one API is needed, i have built a lightweight framework that works with both flask and falcon, that let's you configure different apis with it's own endpoints, and lets you get up and running super fast.

you can check it here: https://github.com/sebastiandev/peach